# What is the actual meaning of these lines and what time (Past/Present/Future) it indicates?

Tags: grammar, lyrics

These lines have been taken from Shakira's Whenever, Wherever song lyric,

"Never could imagine there were only
Ten million ways to love somebody".

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The singer says that she could never imagine that there were only ten million ways to love someone.

"Could" shows that the sentence is in past tense (past of "can")

Comment: Thanks Bella.., You are awesome..!

Comment: Actually, *could*, on its own, isn't past tense. (*I **could never** do that to you* is future hypothetical.) It's *never could* (in that specific order—and with an assumed *could never* ***[have imagined]***) that is past tense. However, the essential answer here is correct.

Comment: @JasonBassford I know, could can have multiple meanings, but here it shows past tense specifically